# Documenting namespaces with Doxygen

Tags: c++, namespaces, doxygen, documentation-generation, doxygen-addtogroup

I'm having issues with Doxygen recognizing namespaces and modules.  I believe the issue surrounds whether to place the `\addtogroup` within the namespace or outside the namespace.

### Example 1, outside the namespace:

```
/*!
 *  \addtogroup Records
 *  @{
 */

//! Generic record interfaces and implementations
namespace Records
{

  //! Describes the record interface  
  class Interface;

} // End namespace Records

/*! @} End of Doxygen Groups*/
```

### Example 2 - within namespace

```
//! Generic record interfaces and implementations
namespace Records
{
/*!
 *  \addtogroup Records
 *  @{
 */


  //! Describes the record interface  
  class Interface;

/*! @} End of Doxygen Groups*/

} // End namespace Records
```

I would like the `namespace Records` to appear under the Doxygen *Namespaces* tab and indirectly under the *Modules* tab.  Clicking on the item in the *Namespaces* page should produce a page containing `Records::Interface`.  Clicking on the item in the *Modules* tab should also produce a page containing `Records::Interface`.

In my Doxygen documentation, I have items missing from *Namespaces* tab that are in *Modules* and vice-versa, due to my inconsistency resulting from this dilemma.

So which is the proper method, Example 1 or Example 2?
{The Doxygen manual is not clear on this topic.}
[Doxygen: \addtogroup](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdaddtogroup)
[Doxygen: documenting namespaces](http://www.doxygen.nl/docblocks.html)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I have performed an experiment using Doxygen and the two examples and here are the results.
The class names in the examples have been renamed to avoid confusion with Doxygen.

## Example 1, Outside Namespace

```
/*!
 *  \addtogroup Records
 *  @{
 */

//! Generic record interfaces and implementations
namespace Records
{

  //! Describes the record interface  
  class Interface;

} // End namespace Records

/*! @} End of Doxygen Groups*/
```

### Doxygen Results:

Click on Modules button (in the main bar).
Click on "Records" module in the window.

[image: Records & Namespaces screen snapshot]

## Example 2: Within Namespace (class renamed to Fields)

```
//! Generic record interfaces and implementations
namespace Fields
{
/*!
 *  \addtogroup Fields
 *  @{
 */


  //! Describes the record interface  
  class Interface;

/*! @} End of Doxygen Groups*/

} // End namespace Fields
```

### Doxygen Results:

Click on Modules button (in the main bar).
Click on "Records" module in the window.

[image: Records & Namespaces screen snapshot within namespace]

## Summary

The location of Doxygen `\addtogroup` command has different results depending on whether it is located within a `namespace` definition or outside.  When declared outside of a namespace, the Doxygen *Modules* tab will show the namespace, as shown in Example 1 above.  When the `\addtogroup` command is placed inside a namespace, the Doxygen *Modules* tab will not display the namespaces as shown in Example 2 above.  **If you want your namespace to be listed in the Doxygen *Modules* tab, locate the `\addtogroup` command outside of the namespace.**

Comment: Nice. I was actually searching for an answer to a similar question. Good to see that there is a solution :)

Comment: Any chance to get those images back again? It's a great answer!

Comment: @MPelletier:  New pictures added, plus steps to get to the pages in question.

Comment: What if I don't care about modules at all, and just want to have my namespace listed as such?

Comment: @einpoklum You should post to the Doxygen forum.  Check out the website for instructions.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative, you could also use [`\ingroup`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdingroup)`Records` in the namespace documentation:

```
/**
 * \defgroup Records Title for records module
 * @brief Short doc of Records
 *
 * Long doc of Records.
 */

/**
 * @brief Generic record interfaces and implementations
 *
 * \ingroup Records
 */
namespace Records {
    /// Describes the record interface  
    class Interface;

} /* namespace Records */
```